# List all Quarkus Managed Built-in Beans

Tags: javabeans, quarkus

Spring Boot has actuator that can list Spring Managed Beans by going to /beans endpoint. What is the quarkus equivalent of this? I know that we can programmatically use ...

```java
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;

...
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class,new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {}));

for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
     System.out.println(bean.getBeanClass().getName());
}
```

But it can be useful if there's equivalent like Spring Actuator or at least a documentation.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2763